# Looking for a cartoon where three kids wake up in a different world

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember watching this cartoon as a child. In the first episode these three kids went camping with their parents. The parents slept in one tent and the kids in another. But when the kids wake up the next morning and exit the tent they find that they are in a different world/dimension with all these alien plants and monsters. I think they went to a different world every day to try and get back to their parents. 
All three kids were siblings. They were different ages but I don't think any of them could have been older than 14-15. I think the youngest was still little. at least one of the kids was a girl. Some of the monsters helped them, but others were dangerous. I don't think there was a reoccurring villain in the show.

The show aired where I live(Estonia) in the middle of the '00s or so(2005-2010 I think), but we often get shows a few years after their release and this was definitely a foreign show so it could have been made in the 90s too.

This has been driving me up the wall for a few years now and I just can't find it. At this point I would be happy just to find someone else who has seen it and can confirm I'm not crazy!

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what ages were the kids? What were their genders? What race/ethnicity were they? Were they all related to each other? What was the animation style? When were you a child? Was the cartoon new then? What country do you live in? What did the monsters look like? Were the monsters unfriendly? Was there a human villain? What were the kids names?

Comment: "The Hollow" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hollow_(TV_series)) seems too recent.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - lol. Yes. *"When I was a kid (**last year**) I watched a show..."*

Comment: ^_^ Indeed. But I like mentioning ones that don't match on the time frame because it sometimes leads to someone saying, "Wait, there was a show just like that in the 90s named *X*!"

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I edited the question and added some more details that I remember. Sadly my memory is a bit fuzzy :(

Comment: @magictent: Thank you for sticking with it.

Comment: I notice that your username is "magictent", which makes me wonder, was it shown that the tent was what was transporting them?

Comment: If K. Mo (or anyone else) has the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Thank you all so much!! It was indeed Lili's island! I am super happy!

Comment: Congratulations on getting your question answered. :) I hope you'll stick around to ask more!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be [Lili's Island](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt7334898/). It was produced in 2006, so fits the time frame.

[image: Lili]

> Lili, her little sister Glueball and their best friend Matt, spend the
>   first night of their summer vacation at the Palavas-les-flots camping
>   ground. Pure ecstasy. But no way are they going to sleep in their
>   family campers. The next morning though, when they come out of their
>   tent, they discover that they are on a mysterious island, inhabited by
>   strange people and even weirder creatures. And it's going to take 26
>   episodes for our little heroes to find their parents and their way
>   back to the camp site.

So it has the three kids, the camping trip and the weird world. Although it is only the one island they travel, each episode is quite different. For example, episode one has them riding walking bushes and parts of episode three looks like it is set in a kid's sketch book.

### Show Credits